# How would I create a python function that outputs all combinations of a defined set of variables?

Tags: python

Here is what I am trying to do but not exactly sure how to make this work. I have 3 sets of variables and I want to output all combinations of those 3 sets and output in a format that maintains the order of the variables like this:

```
list_of_vars = [var1, var2, var3]
```

The variables would look something like this:

```
var1 = [1, 2, 3]
var2 = ["foo", "bar", "foo2"]
var3 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

The final output should look like this.

```
final_list_of_vars = [[1, "foo", a], [1, "bar", a], .......]
```

Comment: Can you explain how the info in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements) didn't help here?

Comment: The question has already been answerd here,

Comment: Thanks. Wrong wording for my search so I never found the answer you posted.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to iterate through those variables and make a new list with them.

Here is the sample code:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list3 = ["Hello", "World","Python"]
answer = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        for k in list3:
            answer.append([i,j,k])
print(answer)
```

Here's the sample result:

> [[1, 'a', 'Hello'], [1, 'a', 'World'], [1, 'a', 'Python'], [1, 'b', 'Hello'], [1, 'b', 'World'], [1, 'b', 'Python'], [1, 'c', 'Hello'], [1, 'c', 'World'], [1, 'c', 'Python'], [1, 'd', 'Hello'], [1, 'd', 'World'], [1, 'd', 'Python'], [1, 'e', 'Hello'], [1, 'e', 'World'], [1, 'e', 'Python'], [2, 'a', 'Hello'], [2, 'a', 'World'], [2, 'a', 'Python'], [2, 'b', 'Hello'], [2, 'b', 'World'], [2, 'b', 'Python'], [2, 'c', 'Hello'], [2, 'c', 'World'], [2, 'c', 'Python'], [2, 'd', 'Hello'], [2, 'd', 'World'], [2, 'd', 'Python'], [2, 'e', 'Hello'], [2, 'e', 'World'], [2, 'e', 'Python'], [3, 'a', 'Hello'], [3, 'a', 'World'], [3, 'a', 'Python'], [3, 'b', 'Hello'], [3, 'b', 'World'], [3, 'b', 'Python'], [3, 'c', 'Hello'], [3, 'c', 'World'], [3, 'c', 'Python'], [3, 'd', 'Hello'], [3, 'd', 'World'], [3, 'd', 'Python'], [3, 'e', 'Hello'], [3, 'e', 'World'], [3, 'e', 'Python'], [4, 'a', 'Hello'], [4, 'a', 'World'], [4, 'a', 'Python'], [4, 'b', 'Hello'], [4, 'b', 'World'], [4, 'b', 'Python'], [4, 'c', 'Hello'], [4, 'c', 'World'], [4, 'c', 'Python'], [4, 'd', 'Hello'], [4, 'd', 'World'], [4, 'd', 'Python'], [4, 'e', 'Hello'], [4, 'e', 'World'], [4, 'e', 'Python']]